# Restkit Mapping - Use Embedded Object/Relationship As Identification Attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having trouble mapping a particular JSON structure, as illustrated in a simplified form here:

```
{"personDetails":{"eyeColor":"brown",
                  "height":"2m 12cm",
                  "specialRestrictions":null,
                  "person":{"personId":42,
                            "firstName":"Hummingbird",
                            "lastName":"Collins",
                            "dob":1360856245000,
                            "gender":"F",
                            "personCode":"8DECCC6D-68CA-47E1-AV7F-84C2039D517",
                            "isAdmin":false}
                  }
}
```

In this case, I'd like to use the `"personId"` field, or even the `"person"` object itself, as a primary key of my `"personDetails"` object. As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this. I looked into `RKConnectionDescription`, but it doesn't seem applicable in this case, since the entire object is embedded, not just a foreign key attribute.

I basically want the relationship to be one-to-one, in that, when I call my service, like this,

```
http://server/services/getPersonDetailsByID/42
```

the details can map and persist in CoreData, overwriting the `PersonDetails` for that `Person` that were previously saved. At the moment, multiple `PersonDetails` objects can exist for the same `Person` locally, because there is no key in place.

So, my question is this: can RestKit mapping be set up to accomplish this intended behavior? Or will I need to handle the deletion of any outdated CoreData objects myself?

Edit:
Here's how my mapping looks currently.

```
RKEntityMapping* personDetailsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:
          @"personDetails" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
[personDetailsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"eyeColor", @"height",  
                                                         @"specialRestrictions"]];
[personDetailsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
          relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"person" toKeyPath:@"person" 
                     withMapping:personMapping]]; // personMapping defined earlier
```

Here are two different ways I've tried adding an Identification attribute:

```
personDetailsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"person"];
```

and

```
personDetailsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"personId"];
```

at different times, and they each throw an error like this:

```
Invalid attribute 'personId': no attribute was found for the given name in the 'PersonDetails' entity.
```

Comment: Did you try adding the key path as the identification attribute? Otherwise you can setup your mapping to copy the person id into the details object.

Comment: I tried `personDetailsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"person"];` and `personDetailsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"personId"];`, and both of those threw an error. Is there a way to specify the attribute of a sub-object? And how can you set up the mapping to copy the attribute into the Details object like you say?

Comment: In both cases, use a key path `person.personId`. I haven't tried it for the identification attribute but works for copying the id.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. I think I'll have to add personId as an attribute of my object in CoreData, then copy into that attribute.

Comment: Yes, you will need to add an attribute if you go for the copy option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that adding the key path as the identification attribute will work. I haven't actually tried it but key paths work in most places.

```
personDetailsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"person.personId" ]
```

If it doesn't, you can setup your mapping to copy the person id into the details object. You will need to add a new persistent attribute and then you use the key path in the mapping:

```
@"personId" : @"person.personId"
```

Comment: The second solution worked for me, but the first one doesn't work. Apparently, in this case at least, RestKit can't traverse through a relationship to identify using a sub-object's attribute.

Comment: I had the same experience.  The first solution raises an invalid attribute exception inside RestKit, e.g "Invalid attribute 'primaryView.url': no attribute was found for the given name in the 'Server' entity".  Adding a new attribute using `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary` did the trick nicely.